# Mail::Header - can't get it to show me the headers

Tags: perl

I'm trying to work out how to use this **Perl module**:

http://search.cpan.org/~markov/MailTools-2.18/lib/Mail/Header.pod

I have tried a couple of ways:

```
my $fh = open (READIT, "./test.eml");

use Mail::Header;
my $head = Mail::Header->new();
   $head->read($fh);

print Dumper($head);
```

All that does though, is print out some empty values:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'mail_hdr_foldlen' => 79,
                 'mail_hdr_modify' => 0,
                 'mail_hdr_list' => [],
                 'mail_hdr_hash' => {},
                 'mail_hdr_mail_from' => 'KEEP',
                 'mail_hdr_lengths' => {}
               }, 'Mail::Header' );
```

I've also tried it using the email as a string, in **$message**:

```
my $head = Mail::Header->new( $message );
```

Same problem though.

I'm a bit confused as to what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone suggest something to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have opened your .eml file using the `READIT` handle, but you are then reading from file handle `$fh` to populate the `Mail::Header` object. You will also have received the warning messages

> Name "main::READIT" used only once: possible typo

and

> Name "main::fh" used only once: possible typo

which you really should have reported

This program works fine

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Mail::Header;

open my $fh, '<', 'Support Account Password Assistance.eml' or die $!;
my $head = Mail::Header->new($fh);
print $head->as_string;
```

When used with this file for input

#### simple.eml

```
From: example@example.com
To: example2@example.com
Subject: As basic as it gets

This is the plain text body of the message.  Note the blank line
between the header information and the body of the message.
```

It generates this output

#### output

```
From: example@example.com
To: example2@example.com
Subject: As basic as it gets
```

Comment: Ah - you beauty! It looks like I just had the filehandle part wrong. Once I have the head, you can just use: `$head->get("Subject")` ... and that works like a charm. Thanks!